# DocuSign URL Button in Lightning CRL values not populating

Tags: lightning, custom-button, docusign

I need help with a Lightning custom "Send to DocuSign" button. I can't get the CRL variable to populate the Candidate's Name or Email address from the record that I am on when I click "Send to DocuSign". (see screenshot below) I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use URLENCODE or something else.

{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [ SourceID = Job_Applications_1__c.Id, CRL ='Email~ URLENCODE(Job_Applications_1__c.Candidate_Email__c};LastName~Job_Applications_1__c.Name ;Role~R1;RoutingOrder~1,
CCRM = 'R1~Candidate',CCTM = 'R1~Signer',CES = 'RL Canning Inc. Background Authorization Forms--Request Completion',CEM = 'Hello- Your Background Authorization document is waiting for you to fill out, please follow the link to DocuSign to fill in the necessary information. If you have any questions contact HR@NAME.com. Thank you!',DST = '',LA = '0']
)}

[image]